# Mongo db import / export Object id overwritten

Tags: node.js, mongodb

In my Mongo DB I have a number of collections that reference each other using the auto generated unique Object id e.g ObjectId("5459a7fb3fcd7efe772c0816");

Now, that's all fine.

I'm currently developing on the site on two different setups, importing / exporting my collections in order to format the data and keep it in sync. When doing so new Object Ids are created disregarding the existing ones. This causes the app to break since my application references ids across different collections.

Would it be better for me to create my own id and disregard the Object id?
Or is there an entirely different approach all together?

Comment: You're clearly doing it wrong. mongoexport / mongoimport are provided utilities that preserve types such as `ObjectId` under the extended JSON format. In a similar manner the mongodump / mongorestore utilities also directly preserves data in a binary form.

Comment: Yes. I was doing it wrong. When the utilities are properly used Object Ids are maintained.

Answer (score -6):

The answer to this question is: Read the documentation! http://docs.mongodb.org/manual/tutorial/backup-with-mongodump/

Comment: I know this question is like 6 years old, but I'm experiencing a similar issue, and this isn't super helpful. I doubt you remember what you did, but next time could you provide some details as to what you did to correct the problem other than a link to a long docs page?